# Probability Expectation Mean

Tags: probability, expectation

A box contains $10$ blue balls, $7$ red balls, & $8$ green balls. $8$ balls are selected simultaneously from the box. What is the expected number of distinct colors among these 8 balls?

Answer: 
$$3-\frac{\binom{15}{8} +\binom{18}{8}  + \binom{17}{8} }{\binom{25}{8}}$$

Comment: I don't think the answer is 3. There is a positive probability of 2 or 3 colors, so the expectation should be in between.

Comment: I edited your question, please check it still says what you want it to say.

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking why that's the answer? In any case, my attempt below is one way of approaching it, which yields the same result as yours.

Answer (score 2):

Hi sorry I can't comment yet but in @remy's answer, there is a double counting in $P\left(\text {seeing 2 colors}\right)$. The discrepancy is just very small that it doesn't show up in the decimals.

So here is my attempt:
\begin{align}
& P\left(X=1\right)=\frac{{10\choose8}+{8\choose8}}{25\choose8} 
=\frac{46}{1081575} \\
& P\left(X=2\right)=\frac{{\sum_{r=1}^{7}{10\choose r}{7\choose 8-r}}+{\sum_{r=1}^{7}{10\choose r}{8\choose 8-r}}+{\sum_{r=1}^{7}{8\choose r}{7\choose 8-r}}}{25\choose8}=\frac{74411}{1081575} \\
& P\left(X=3\right)=\frac{{\sum_{r=1}^{6}{10\choose r}\left({\sum_{k=1}^{7-r}{8\choose k}{7\choose 8-r-k}}\right)}}{25\choose8}=\frac{1007118}{1081575} \\
&\operatorname{E}\left(X\right)=1\cdot\frac{46}{1081575}+2\cdot\frac{74411}{1081575}+3\cdot\frac{1007118}{1081575}=\frac{3170222}{1081575}
 \end{align}
which is consistent with the answer given in the question.

Note: for $P\left(X=3\right)$ the more convenient and exam-friendly way is to use complements but I used cases just to check if there is any mistake in $P\left(X=1\right)$ and $P\left(X=2\right)$.